Setting model height for .stl output in QGIS (DEMto3D plugin v3.6)
I'm running QGIS 3.28 and 3.34 with DEMto3D v3.6 plugin and I'm not able to figure out the Model Height settings to create a proper .stl model. Everything seems backwards and upside down and sometimes I can only get the terrain to model using negative numbers. Things get even more strange when I've got bathymetric data included with the terrain which itself is a negative number.
The entry fields Height(m) and Base height(mm) don't seem to make much sense. I've attempted every combination I can think of while tracking results and it seems impossible to make sense of.
Can anyone define these settings or explain how the software understands these inputs?
